# Quantifier scope

Tags: predicate-logic

I'm having trouble understanding predicate logic. I get very confused in interpreting the parentheses, to be able to correctly demarcate the scope of quantifiers, particularly in the following (from our unit book):

### (x)(Bx → (Cx & ~Dx)) & ((∃y)(Ey & Fy) v (∃z)((~Jz & ~Kz) → (w) Mwz))

Is this correct? Can you please explain where I'm wrong? Thank you!

(x) : Scope is (Bx → (Cx & ~Dx). The x in Bx, Cx, and ~Dx, are bound to (x).

(∃y) : Scope is (Ey & Fy). The y in Ey and Fy are bound to (∃y).

(∃z) : Scope is (~Jz & ~Kz) → (w) Mwz). The z in ~Jz, ~Kz, and Mwz, are bound to (∃z).

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Count the parentheses...

Comment: Yes, the scope of the leftmost universal quantifier $(x)$ is (Bx → (Cx &  ~ Dx))

Comment: And Yes and Yes (but the parentheses in your sub-formulas must match.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you! Are you able to elaborate further about the parentheses, because I'm still new to this. So, in another example: (x)((Bx → (Cx & ~Dx)) & (y)(Cx & Ly)), does (x) govern ((Bx → (Cx & ~Dx)) & (y)(Cx & Ly))? Or does it only govern ((Bx → (Cx & ~Dx)), because of the double brackets?

Comment: If you have a formula $\forall x ( Px \to Qxy)$ the scope of the quantifier is explicitly stated; it is : $Px \to Qxy$. If instead you have $\forall x  Px \to Qxy$ the scope is "narrow : only $Px$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all correct. Also, the scope of the $(w)$ is $Mwz$

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. If you have a formula (w)Mww, is it only the first 'w' that is bound (w), or are the two w's both bound to (w), since they're the same?

Comment: @explorer Both $w$’s would be bound to $(w)$ since both occur within the scope of $(w)$. Usually, parentheses are used to indicate the scope, as in $(w)(P(w)\to Q(w))$, but if there are no parentheses, then the scope is limited to the first term that follows it. So, with $(w)mww$ the scope is limited to $Mww$, but that would still cover both $w$’s

Comment: That's really making sense to me now. That leads me to wonder about a scenario (I hope you don't mind answering). How would you translate (x)(Mxx), if x is, say, a mother? Would it be that x is a mother herself? @Bram28

Comment: @explorer it would mean that everyone is a mother of themselves.